# How to create QR Code for each register user?

Tags: php, qr-code

I would like my user after register an account on my website and have their own unique QR code. The QR code will only contain the member serial number and for us to scan whether the user is truly our member. So may I ask everyone how am I going to achieve that and with what? My entire website is using PHP to write.

Comment: I saw one tutorial http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/
Find the Dcoumentation http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html
And Also See this example http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to generate qr code in php

```
<body onload="loadGraph()">
   <form action='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart' method='POST' id='post_form' onsubmit="this.action = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chid=' + (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
return true;">  <input type='hidden' name='cht' value='qr' />
<input type='hidden' name='cht' value='qr' />
<input type='hidden' name='chs' value='300x300' />
<input type='hidden' name='chl' value='This is your QR code. You need to pass the users serial number here  '/>
 <input type='submit' value="Download your Qr code Here" />
</form>
```

change the code accordingly for your requirement.